# 127.0.0.1:8080 works but localhost:8080 doesn't

Tags: port-forwarding, localhost, hosts

This may be super easy so I apologize in advance but my strengths are in coding.

Why can't I access my localhost at localhost:8080?
127.0.0.1:8080 - works
127.0.0.1:80 - doesn't work
127.0.0.1 - doesn't work

localhost - works
localhost:80 - forwards to localhost and works
localhost:8080 - doesn't work

I am trying to adjust my hosts/etc file to include

```
localhost  sandbox.dev
```

In turn I would like to access my app at sandbox.dev:8080/test-file.php.  So far, I haven't been successful so any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Describing a problem as "doesn't work" is not really very helpful. What *exactly* happens when you try it? How far do you get? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hosts file needs the first entry on each line to be an ip address, like

`127.0.0.1 localhost sandbox.dev`